# Regex search and replace: How to move characters in a block of text

Tags: python, regex, replace

I'm having a search and replace problem. Take this example.

I want to go from:

```
"Word1 word2 =word3 *word4 word5= word6 word7* (*word8)"
```

To this:

```
"Word1 word2 word3= word4* word5= word6 word7* word8*"
```

i.e. To replace any word starting a * or = with itself with the * or = moved to the end of the word, and to make it worse sometimes those words are in brackets, and/or could be at the start or end of a line.

I've tried to search for the solution but I am relatively new at regex and whilst I can cobble together solutions that find the words I am looking for, e.g.:

```
\[\*,\=][a-zA-Z]{1,}[\s,\)]
```

I can't figure out / understand how to do the replace and maintain end of line / start of line characters, white space and brackets.

I am using Python, but if it makes a material difference I'm happy to try using something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ***verbose*** expression like the following:

```
import re
rx = re.compile('''
    \(?    # opening parenthesis or not
    ([*=]) # capture one of * or = to Group 1
    (\w+)  # at least one word chararacter to Group 2
    \)?    # a closing parenthesis
''', re.VERBOSE)

string = "Word1 word2 =word3 *word4 word5= word6 word7* (*word8)"
new_string = rx.sub(r'\2\1', string)
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/YCkISh) and add other characters to the class in square brackets (`[...]`) as needed.

Comment: Works perfectly and I think I even understand it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You need 2 capture group and replace them together:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = "Word1 word2 =word3 *word4 word5= word6 word7* (*word8)"
>>>
>>> re.sub(r'(\*|=)(\b\w+\b)', r'\2\1', s)
'Word1 word2 word3= word4* word5= word6 word7* (word8*)'
```